# добавление данных в таблицы со связями

Tags: sql

Подскажите, как составить запрос на добавление данных в связанные таблицы, имеется Table1(id, name), Table2(id, name, parentid)? Нужно добавить данные в name Table2 с выбором строки по значению Name Table1.
в общем последнее что сделал

```
declare @ids int;
select [КодСИнеСИ], @ids from [ВыборСИнеСИ] where [СИнеСИ] = 'Нет';
INSERT INTO [ВыборВидИзмерения] ([СИнеСИ], [вид измерения]) VALUES ( @ids, 'тест')
```

но в переменной значение null как правильно ее вставить?

Comment: `INSERT .. SELECT` в помощь.

Comment: не помогает, нужно что типа INSERT Table2.name VALUES (data) WHERE Table1.name = 1

Comment: Нет, нужно именно то, что я сказал. Про слово VALUES вообще забудьте.

Comment: Ну напишите пример, а то я немного не догоняю как это сделать, уже штук 50 запросов перепробовал ни черта не получается

Answer (score 0):

Если требуется добавить запись в таблицу Table2 с Name = 'Name 2', а родителем этой записи (parentId) сделать значение Id из Table1, которому соответствует Name = 'Name 1', это делается запросом

```
INSERT INTO Table2 (Name, parentId)
SELECT 'Name 2', Id
FROM Table1
WHERE Name = 'Name 1';
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9c97aff3e5341a01b37f84c6554d0e73

Comment: А для чего в SELECT name2 в кавычках?

Comment: да не, тупанул, спасибо огромное вам за помощь!